# MongoDB: Substitute values in array with data from external array

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

In a MongoDB database, I have this collection:

```json
"cities" {
    "name": "London",
    "suburbs": [
        { "_id: ObjectId('...')", "city_id": 0, "name": "Chelsea", "population": "41k" },
        { "_id: ObjectId('...')", "city_id": 1, "name": "Fulham", "population": "87k" },
        { "_id: ObjectId('...')", "city_id": 2, "name": "Kensington", "population": "64k" }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add values to this collection based on an array of Javascript objects.

The object is this:

```json
let cities = [
    { "team": "Chelsea FC", "division": "premier league", "id": 0 },
    { "team": "Fulham FC", "division": "premier league", "id": 1 },
    { "team": "Kensington FC", "division": "CCFL", "id": 2 }
]
```

At the moment, I solved with a for loop in Javascript, like this:

```js
for(let o = 0; o < cities.length; o++) {
    db.cities.updateOne(
        { "name": "London", "suburbs.city_id": cities[o].id },
        {
            "suburbs.$.team": cities[o].team,
            "suburbs.$.division": cities[o].division
        }
    )
}
```

Is there a way to do everything in one query?

How can I call an external variable in a MongoDB query?

Any help is welcome.

Many thanks

Comment: So far I can, of course, unwind the `suburbs` in the `cities` collection, but I still need that something that says `and now update all of them "where cities.city_id == city.id"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've tried to work on a solution.

You can check it out here  : https://mongoplayground.net/p/DZZy1XXtVv_

```
db.cities.update({
  "name": "London"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "suburbs": {
        $map: {
          input: "$suburbs",
          as: "val",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$val",
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    //input : cities
                    input: [
                      {
                        "team": "Chelsea FC",
                        "division": "premier league",
                        "id": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "team": "Fulham FC",
                        "division": "premier league",
                        "id": 1
                      },
                      {
                        "team": "Kensington FC",
                        "division": "CCFL",
                        "id": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    as: "team",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$val.city_id",
                        "$$team.id"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I'm going to try it ASAP!!! :d

Comment: Hi @Fourchette, this works (tweaking a bit the document properties). Many thanks